# How to redirect http get to perl script

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to get any HTTP GET requests to one directory on my server (/temp/downloads/target) to be redirected to a perl cgi script....basically making the request: http://www.myserver.com/cgi/perlscript.cgi?path=target

Can this be easily done with htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^temp/downloads/(.*)$ /cgi/perlscript.cgi?path=$1 [L]
```